# Is the rotation of Gravity Probe B's frame dragging precession in the same direction or opposite direction of Earth's rotation?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

First, thank you to the community for answering questions like this, it is much appreciated.  Second, I did try to find the answer online first, and I believe from some images that the direction of rotation about a North-South axis line is the same as that of Earth, but I could not find any definitive statement to that effect.

That is, looking down on the Earth from above the North Pole, our planet rotates counter clockwise.

I believe that, viewing from this position, the GP-B satellite rotates counter clockwise (same as the Earth) when above the North pole, and clockwise (the opposite of the Earth) when above the Equator.  The net effect is a rotation of about 39 milliarcseconds per year as described at https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0802/0802.3346.pdf.  I am just double checking - Is that net rotation counter clockwise (same as Earth) as viewed from above the North Pole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct at the North pole and at the equator. As shown by eqn 1.10 of the arxiv paper you reference:
$$
\vec{\Omega} = \frac{G}{c^2}(\frac{3\vec{S}*\vec{R}}{R^5}\vec{R}-\frac{\vec{S}}{R^3})
$$
where $\vec{\Omega}$ is the angular velocity of precession of the test mass, $\vec{S}$ is the angular momentum vector of the earth and $\vec{R}$ is the vector from the earth's center to the satellite. At the north pole $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{R}$ are in the same direction so $\vec{\Omega}_{NP} = \frac{G}{c^2}(\frac{2\vec{S}}{R^3})$ while at the equator $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{R}$ are perpendicular so $\vec{\Omega}_{EQ} = -\frac{G}{c^2}(\frac{\vec{S}}{R^3})$.

As you say, the GP-B satellite rotates the same as the Earth when above the North pole (and the South pole), and the opposite of the Earth when above the Equator. The satellite is in a polar orbit.   The integrated precession over the orbit is -39 mas/yr which is in the opposite direction to the earth's angular momentum, and therefore is clockwise when looking down on the North pole.